# Getting SpriteKit texture from SKView returning nil after 104 calls

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

I am having some odd behavior in SpriteKit when creating a texture. The function below shows you what I am doing. In short, I'm in SceneKit and making a SCNNode out of an Array of colors (think pixel/voxels). It works like a charm. However, after exactly 104 calls the texture returned is nil. Afterwards, it is hit or miss whether the texture will be nil or not. I am also providing the exact color information. Thoughts?

```
   func create2dModelSK(with colors: [String]) -> SCNNode? {
    let geo = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.0)

    let base = SCNNode(geometry: geo)

    let view = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 160))
    view.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    var xOffset = 0
    var yOffset = 0
    var count = 0
    for _ in 0...15 {
        for _ in 0...15 {
            guard let newColor = UIColor(hexString: "#" + colors[count] + "ff") else { return base }

            let n = SKSpriteNode(color: newColor, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
            n.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            n.position = CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
            view.addChild(n)
            xOffset += 10
            count += 1
        }
        xOffset = 0
        yOffset -= 10
    }
    let skView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 160))

    let texture = skView.texture(from: view)
    //AFTER being called 104 times, texture is nil.
    let faceMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    faceMaterial.diffuse.contents = texture

    let sideMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

    let materialsForBox = [faceMaterial,sideMaterial,faceMaterial,sideMaterial,sideMaterial,sideMaterial]
    base.geometry?.materials = materialsForBox

    let scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)
    base.scale = scale

    return base
}
```

Comment: You are running out of texture space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `autoreleasepool` comes in handy,  it allows you to release the memory when the `autoreleasepool` is finished so that you do not run out of space before using it again.

Of course this is not going to solve your main problem, where you are creating too many textures and running out of memory space, but it will allow you to at least make some more because it will release the temporary memory that `view.texture(from:node)` is holding on to.

```
func create2dModelSK(with colors: [String]) -> SCNNode? {
    let geo = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.0)

    let base = SCNNode(geometry: geo)

    let view = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 160))
    view.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    var xOffset = 0
    var yOffset = 0
    var count = 0
    for _ in 0...15 {
        for _ in 0...15 {
            guard let newColor = UIColor(hexString: "#" + colors[count] + "ff") else { return base }

            let n = SKSpriteNode(color: newColor, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
            n.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            n.position = CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
            view.addChild(n)
            xOffset += 10
            count += 1
        }
        xOffset = 0
        yOffset -= 10
    }
    autoreleasepool{
        let skView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 160))

        let texture = skView.texture(from: view)
        //AFTER being called 104 times, texture is nil.
        let faceMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        faceMaterial.diffuse.contents = texture

        let sideMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

        let materialsForBox = [faceMaterial,sideMaterial,faceMaterial,sideMaterial,sideMaterial,sideMaterial]
        base.geometry?.materials = materialsForBox
    }
    let scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)
    base.scale = scale

    return base
}
```

Comment: BTW avoid calling nodes "views" because that only adds to the confusion

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there a better way to think about adding this many textures? I wouldn't think I'd need more than 1000.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am adding SCNNodes to an ARKit Scene. Each node needs it's own texture with the data provided to the function above. The data is being provided from many locations, but they would all feed into the scene.

Comment: Also, calling autoreleasepool in your answer does not work as it becomes it's own scope.

Comment: i do not see anything warranting a texture, all i see are checkerboard patterns.  You could use an SKS file to create and archive your checkerboard nodes, then just change what color gets blended with the square.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170105/discussion-between-hartix-and-knight0fdragon).